# jquery dialog causes jsp action on page

Tags: jquery, jsp

To load my page I use action `ResponseAction.do`.

```
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    session.setAttribute("responses", clientService.getReponses());

    session.setAttribute("classes", clasService.getClasses());

    return "book";
```

Where `book` - name of the page. 
On the page there is a dialog form

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="<fmt:message key='book'/>"
    style="font-family: times new roman;">
    <p class="validateTips">
        <fmt:message key="tips" />
    </p>
    <form action="BookRoomAction.do">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="apart"><fmt:message key="aclass" /></label> <select
                id="apart" name="classid"><c:forEach items="${classes}"
                    var="classes">
                    <option value="${classes.id}">${classes.id}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> <label for="beds"><fmt:message key="beds_n" /></label> <input
                type="text" id="beds" name="beds" /> <label for="days"><fmt:message
                    key="days_n" /></label> <input type="text" id="days" name="days" /> <label
                for="fio"><fmt:message key="fio" /></label> <input type="text"
                id="fio" name="fio" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

But when I press button to open it

```
$( "#request" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
```

it opens and closes immediately. In debugger I found out that when I press button it causes `ResponseAction.do` again.

How to solve this problem? Button on the page is

```
<button id="request" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-widget-content">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set type of button.